# Does the "Go outside" achievement keep track of time across machines?

Tags: steam, achievements, the-stanley-parable

I'm currently in the process of unlocking the "Go outside" achievement in The Stanley Parable (in other words, I haven't touched the game in quite a while). I'm aware there are ways to unlock this achievement by changing the system time settings, but I'd rather unlock it the legitimate way.

However, I'm about to get a new computer and I'm not sure if I'll be able to keep my "progress". Normally I'd assume the game stores a timestamp of my last play session in a cloud save, but since the system time appears to be involved, I'm not so sure. I'm afraid that if I launch the game on my new machine, it will think I've never played it before, even if five years have passed in reality.

Do I have to start the game on the same computer after five years to get the achievement, or will Steam keep track of the timespan for me?

Comment: Couldn't you just set your 'pooter clock 5 years forward?

Comment: @user1337 I could, but as I said, I'd prefer not to (feels like cheating).

Comment: ಠ_ಠ I certainly admire your dedication.

Comment: @Andii Why does it feel like cheating? Changing the clock is most likely the *intended* method of getting that achievement. It's just that kind of game.

Comment: @Michaellogg Well, the creator said something about possibly resetting that achievement's stats shortly before the game's five year anniversary, so I wouldn't be too sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know from [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2229604) (it talks about SquareLogic, but it should applies to all games), Steam check your SteamID to calculate achievements. So, if you change your computer but you're going to use the same account name, you should get the achievement.

Comment: This is true for all achievements in all games, but doesn't say anything about how individual achievements are unlocked by the games.

Comment: While I'm not sure if it's for the reason stated in this answer, I can now confirm that it is indeed correct. It's been more than 5 years since the last time I launched the game, I had gotten a new PC since, just installed and started the game again, and got the achievement. :)

Comment: @Andii Can you post that as an answer? (I was about to post myself before seeing this comment)

Comment: @Stevoisiak I could, but I'm not sure if it's different enough from this answer to be acceptable? StackExchange often seem like they don't appreciate duplicates, and I'm not sure if I should take the checkmark away just for that either^^'

Comment: @Andii I'd argue yours is a better answer because you tried it yourself. Ixpo's answer reads more like an informed guess and relies on a forum post which no longer exists.

Comment: @Andii I agree with Stevoisiak. The answer I provided was based on informations gathered around Steam forums at the time, and since at that time wasn't possible to get that achievement, the simple fact you tried it by yourself should be regarded as a tested answer. :)